# Wordpress debug.log Continues to fill up the same error again and again

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, woocommerce

I am having a strange problem that I have never see before.

I turned on the debug mode on the site, and created an error on a file for example header.php file, to test if the errors are recording in the debug.log file as exepted.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

The debug mode should write the errors log only if the page with the error is loaded,
But in this case the error is recorded over and over again, non-stop even if I entered the page only once.

after few minutes the debug.log  is blown up with hundreds and thousands of lines of the exact same error.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Would be helpful to know about the error reported.

Comment: I created the error just to test it. for example: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file.. but its record again and again the same error.

Comment: Looks like the file may be corrupted (or has some invisible whitespaces). You could copy the content and paste into a new file and delete the original. Then rename the new one to the original.